# When chekcbox value is `null`, `update` throws error

Tags: apex, json

I have a rest API that would send contact details and salesforce would update the contact as follows:

```
//This input cannot be changed
String j = '{"Id": "0036D00000HPQAZ", "Some_checkbox__c": null}';

Contact c = (Contact)JSON.deserialize(j, Contact.class);

update c;
```

But since the `Some_checkbox__c` field is null, it throws the error:

```
Within 100minutes travel: value not of required type:
```

Is there a way to get around this error without manually parsing the field and setting it to false if null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid any kind of problems with incompatible data types, I recommend the following for normal circumstances:

```
Map<String, sObjectField> fields = sObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
Contact c = (Contact)JSON.deserialize(j, Contact.class);
Contact c2 = new Contact();
Map<String, Object> popFields = c.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
for(String field: popFields.keySet()) {
  Object value = popFields.get(field);
  if(value != null || fields.get(field).getDescribe().isNillable()) {
    c2.put(field, value);
  }
}
upsert c2;
```

This method first copies the record to a temp variable to get the correct data types for all fields, then pulls the values out in to a map, then checks the describe calls to see if a null value is legal or not, and if the value isn't null or is null and can be, we set the value.

This should work for most cases. You might need a special exception for master-detail/relationship fields that do not allow reparenting, though. I also recommend checking the field security to see if the field is writeable before attempting to do so.